# Xamarin Encoding

Tags: xamarin, encoding

I'm trying to adjust the accent in my code but it's not working, like below:

```
byte[] nBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(TagsConvert(texto));
socket.Send(nBytes);
```

The result is like this in the printer: `tri?ngulo`, I need the result to be `triângulo`.

Another previous attempt I made was:

```
byte[] reset = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\x0A");
byte[] nBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TagsConvert(texto));
socket.Send(nBytes);
socket.Send(reset);
```

I wasn't successful either.

Comment: is this specifically for printing?  Have you read the printer docs on encoding?

Comment: Yes, these are specific commands for printing and I read the printer documentation, Xamarin uses C# but it is not working.

Comment: I checked the encoding. For Portuguese, you could use `IBM860`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodinginfo.codepage?view=net-6.0